# How to add next prev button on product_cat page to navigate to other product categories(Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce

I am trying to add next button to switch to second category.
as i have Displayed all products of 1 single category on single page.
Help Needed....

Comment: Google 'wordpress previous_posts_link' and 'wordpress next_posts_link', and take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as per the [wordpress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65450/is-it-possible-to-put-next-and-previous-category-links)...

```
$this_category = get_queried_object();
$categories = get_categories();

foreach( $categories as $position => $cat ) :
    if( $this_category->term_id == $cat->term_id ) :
        $next_cat = $position + 1;
        $prev_cat = $position - 1;
        break;
    endif;
endforeach;

$next_cat = $next_cat == count($categories) ? 0 : $next_cat;
$prev_cat = $prev_cat < 0 ? count($categories) - 1 : $prev_cat;
```

echo 'previous: ' . get_term_link( $categories[$prev_cat] );
echo 'next: ' . get_term_link( $categories[$next_cat] );

...and that should do it :)